# NSArray of object

Tags: nsarray

I know is a simple question but I don´t find the best way to do it.

So, which would be the best way to define a NSSArray where every item is a NSObject.

My object has 3 values (int *size, NSstring *path, *url) and I want to have an array where every position has the 3 values.

NSSArray *myarray;

for exemple :

myarray (position 0) --> size = 12, path C:\tt.text, url = \temp\ios

myarray (position 1) --> size = 232, path C:\ty.text, url = \ios

.
.
.

Please, anyone could said me how I should define the array, the object and how to insert the object into the array ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason you can't use a dictionary? That would be my preference if I was storing multiple values for one object.

```
NSNumber *size;
NSString *path;
NSString *url;
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary size,@"size",path,@"thePath",url,@"theUrl",nil];//the string values are the keys you use to access the values.

You can replace objects as         
[dictionary setObject:urlforKey:@"theUrl"];
```

But for your particular case, I would make a dictionary of dictionaries. So just alloc a dictionary and add in the individual dictionary objects that you have defined above.

If you really want to use an array though, try:

```
 NSObject *object;

 NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:object, nil];
```

Then you'll be able to grab your objects and the parts its made up of using :

```
NSObject *myObject = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

Hope it helps!